# window.history.back() scrolls to lastscroll position rather than next page

Tags: javascript, html

I am using window.history.back(-1) to attempt to go back to the last url, however it will work until i goto another page scroll and enter another page url through click.

Then when i go back to the previous page it scrolls to last position, But when I click the Back button again it just goes back to the scroll position and not the previous page. Even though there was a previous page.

How do I fix this?

```
<div class="button cart-button left-right" >
<button class="btn" onclick="window.history.back(-1)" ><i class="lni lni-pointer-left"></i>Go Back</button>
</div>
```

I have tried using the following but get only the same results.

window.history.go(-1)

I am not sure how else to approach this problem.

Comment: As you scroll, does your URL change?

Answer (score 0):

The `back` method **does not take** in any **parameters**.

It is used to achieve the same effect as `window.history.go(-1)`, but it does not take any arguments.

You can invoke it like this: `window.history.back()`

You can read the documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/back).